# Image not displaying in show blade but displaying in index blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Please I need your help. So am trying to display an image in my view, it quite working on the index blade but not working on the show with the same code.

Here is my code

`<img src="{{asset('/blog_images/'.$post->photo )}}" style="width:300px; height:150px" alt="NO IMAGE">`

I've even gone ahead to try other helpers like public_path, url.

Please note that i inspected on the browser and it returned the full part to the image yet didn't display.

I'm thinking it might have to do with a certain settings somewhere.

Cheers!

Comment: Please look up your question in preview before publish. Some piece of your question is disappear

Comment: My bad, thank you Omer YILMAZ

Answer (score 0):

What is in your Controller show method?)
It must be somthing like this:

```
public function show($id)
    {

        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('post.show', compact('post'));
    }
```

Comment: I'm passing the data through with 'with()', is there any particular reason why I should use compact(). And mind you am receiving the data when I inspect from the browser.

Comment: I'm passing the data through with 'with()', is there any particular reason why I should use compact(). And mind you am receiving the data when I inspect from the browser.  Thank you for your response

Comment: compact will just return an array with your wariables like:

$also_like = Product::inRandomOrder() -> take(4) -> get(); $cart_items = Cart::getContent();
        
        return view('front.cart.index', compact('cart_items', 'also_like'));

Comment: Try remove first slash from {{asset('/blog_images/'.$post->photo )}}